# GCC Version Warning while mex compilation

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu, gcc, mex

While compiling a mex function, I get the following error:

```
Warning: You are using gcc version "4.6.3-1ubuntu5)".  The version
         currently supported with MEX is "4.4.6".
         For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
         http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/
```

Is this error critical, do I need to do anything to fix this?
Any help will be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, having a newer version of compiler for MEX **usually** does not cause problems, but since you can hardly be 100% sure, I'd suggest installing a compatible version of gcc - that should not be a problem, no?

Answer (score -2):

It's a warning, not an error: it *might* work, it *might not*.

(That's from my experience with MATLAB MEX files. IMHO, a better approach is to use either SciPy and NumPy, or move to a compiled language (C, C++, ...) completely.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't simply move to a compiled language or any other python lib because I'm running Robot Operating System and I'm trying to control it remotely by using MATLAB client

Comment: My experience under linux: every time you update a library of gcc, if it breaks mcc, you should reinstall matlab.

Comment: @mozcelikors Give it a try. If it crashes, try with a supported compiler, or with a more recent version of MATLAB. gcc-4.4.6 is very old, gcc's latest supported version is 4.7.

Comment: @Sven I've linked the mex compiler with gcc 4.4.6 by following here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB It works for now, but i think it triggered some other problems.